# How to use TF model for inference while training

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm adapting the [Tensorflow tutorial for sequence to sequence modeling](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/seq2seq/index.html) for my project. Specifically, I am basing my code off of translate.py.

The tutorial computes the perplexity on the dev set every n training steps. I'd instead like to calculate BLEU score on the dev set.

The problem I'm facing is that when creating a model, you specify whether it is forward only or not. Looking through the code, it seems that if it is (which happens when training), at each step the network will not calculate the final output for the input sequence, but will calculate gradients. When it's not forward only (as in the decoding function later in the tutorial), it applies the loop function which feeds the output back into the input for the RNN which allows for the output sequence to be generated. However, it doesn't compute the gradients. So as far as I understand it, you can construct a model for either training (i.e. gradients) or testing (i.e. performing full inference on it).

Since I want to compute the BLEU score, I need some sequence produced by the model which corresponds to an input sequence in the dev set. Because of how the models are constructed, I would need both types of models (forward-only and not forward-only). However, trying to do this (even with a new session and a new variable scope), I can't seem to load the model for inference while I also have a model created for training. Without a new session/variable scope, I get errors about duplicated variables. It would be nice if there were a way to switch the model from not forward-only to forward-only.

In this case, is there any way to perform inference (run the full RNN) while I am also in the scope of training it?

Comment: In general, a trick you can use is that the run() method on a tf.Session only runs the part of the graph necessary to compute the tensors passed as arguments.So one way you may be able to do this is to build the graph for training (including the gradients), but run only the forward part of it (by only requesting the output of the forward computation via the argument to sess.run()).

Comment: In a RNN in Tensorflow you can construct it to either 1) compute gradients or 2) execute a loop function at each run which gets the final output sequence for the RNN. I'm thinking I need to construct two models and share their variables somehow, or take the outputs of the training model and run them through a loop explicitly (though I don't know how to do that).